# On Click Listeners for all categories

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, event-listener

I'm getting an error saying cannot resolve symbol onClickListener in addition to method invocation setOnClickListener may produce java.lang.Nullpointerexception. Any form of help would be appreciated!!

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Find the view that shows the numbers category
    TextView numbers = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numbers);

    //Set a click listener on that view
    numbers.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Create a new intent to open the {@link NumbersActivity}
            Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,  NumbersActivity.class);

            //Start the new activity
            startActivity(numbersIntent);
        }
                               });

    //Set button listener for the view
    //buttonView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting an error saying cannot resolve symbol onClickListener in
>   addition to method invocation setOnClickListener may produce
>   java.lang.Nullpointerexception

Both the `View` and the `DialogInterface` classes have a public `OnClickListener` interface (and countless libraries also). You need to explicitly tell the compiler which one you'd like to use:

```
numbers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

The `NullPointerException` warning is simply because `findViewById()` can return `null`. If you're sure that your `View` will never be `null`, you can simply ignore the warning or use an `assert` statement:

```
TextView numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);
assert numbers != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple null check on the "numbers" variable:

```
if (numbers != null){
  numbers.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()...
}
```